Is the identification of the structure sheaf with particular localisations of the coordinate ring natural?
This feels obvious intuitively, but I want to check I’m not going down a dangerous bend.
Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ be an affine scheme, say with coordinate ring $A := \mathcal{O}_X(X)$. The definition of the structure sheaf I am working with (from Ravi Vakil’s book), is that if $f\in A$, then we define $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))$ to be the localisation of $A$ at those $g$ with $D(f)\subseteq D(g)$, which doesn’t actually depend on the choice of $f$ for the basic open set.
Now there is an obvious isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))\cong A_f$ and moreover if $D(f)\cong D(f^\prime)$ then there is an isomorphism $A_f\cong A_{f^\prime}$. My question is, are these isomorphisms sufficiently natural that I can in general just say - for example when trying to define a morphism of affine schemes - that $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))= A_f$?
I.e. if for each basic open $U$ of $X$ I choose some $f\in A$ with $U = D(f)$, then can I just pretend that $\mathcal{O}_X$ is defined to return $A_f$ on $D(f)$? Will I run into any cases where the choice of isomorphisms becomes incompatible?
I feel the answer should be no, because these morphisms are all induced by a series of universal properties, but if that were the case, then I’d have assumed that would have just been given as the definition for the structure sheaf in the first place.

In order to have an incompatibility you need to specify all four sides of the commutative square. At the moment you only have three; you haven’t specified what the morphisms $A_f \to A_g$ are supposed to be.

Well for there to be such a morphism, we would need $D(g)\subseteq D(f)$, which would imply a power of $g$ was in $(f)$ and so $f$ would be invertible in $A_g$. So we’d just send $a/f$ to $af^{-1}$.
This makes the square commute. I suppose, thinking about it, that should be enough to show I get an isomorphic sheaf if I switch the $A_f$. Unless I’ve made an error on the way, that’s helped clarify my thinking, thanks.
